# Javafx button event needs double clicking

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx scene with several buttons within. The only way that the events of the button will be activated is by double cliking. In fxml the button is using the following action method `onAction="#Button1Action"`. How can I change the functionality of the button1Action event from double click to just one click?

The function onAction:

```
 @FXML
 private void Button1Action(ActionEvent event) {
 }
```

and the fxml code:

```
<Button id="button1" fx:id="button1" maxHeight="1.79.." maxWidth="1.79.." mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Button1Action" text="Answer" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="7" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
        <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="30.0" />
        </GridPane.margin>
</Button>
```

Comment: may you post some snippet? `onAction` isn't fired by double-click but any action.

Comment: I posted the function, which is activated only with double click. Its part of the gridpane of the fxml.

Comment: Not sure what exactly should I poste, since the code inside the Button1Action does not contain any event handler.

Comment: Create a [MCVE] and post it in the question. It's not possible to diagnose the problem from these snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not posted the body of `Button1Action`, but most probably it is looking like:

```
@FXML
private void Button1Action(ActionEvent event) {
    button1.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Button clicked"));
}
```

What happens here, that you assign the listener inside the listener, so the actual listener body will be executed on the second click.

Trivial fix is:

```
@FXML
private void Button1Action(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Button clicked");
}
```

Comment: My code is as your second example. This is the strange thing. I dont have setOnAction inside the code.

Comment: In this case please update your question with an example.